# Como mudar o estilo de um component que foi importado em react com styled-component

Tags: javascript, react

Criei um componente chamado "SearchBox":

```
const Input = styled.input`
border: 1px solid black;
width: 450px;
margin-right: ${props => props.marginRight == "ativo" ? '100px' : '0px'};
`;
```

O importei em App.js e passei dentro da tag "SearchBox" uma propriedade chamada "marginRight"

```
<SearchBox type="text" marginRight = "ativo" />
<SearchBox type="text" />
```

Porém, o margin-right não está ocorrendo em nenhum dos dois inputs... mesmo eu passando o valor "ativo" na propriedade marginRight

Site: https://livraria-cactus.vercel.app/

Comment: Opa, fale leonardo, você pode dá mais detalhe do seu código? porquê rodei um exemplo aqui e funcionou normal, o seu dá algum erro?

Comment: você criou um componente com o nome Input e utilizou SearchBox, vale lembrar que colocar o exemplo mínimo faz total diferença na resposta.

Comment: Olá pessoal, agradeço a ajuda de vocês, aqui funcionou sim, desculpem a demora para responder, fiquei sem computador por uns tempos... Obrigado mesmo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basicamente eu fiz o teste no seu código e está funcionando perfeitamente, claro que utilize `<Input />` que foi o componente declarado, ***exemplo***:

```js
const Input = window.styled.input`
border: 1px solid black;
width: 200px;
height: 24px;
margin-right: ${props => props.marginRight === "ativo" ? '100px' : '0px'};
`;

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Input marginRight="ativo"/>
      <Input />
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render( <App/> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script><script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/react-is/umd/react-is.production.min.js"></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/styled-components/dist/styled-components.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">Carregando ...</div>
```

Geralmente quando se faz esse tipo de abordagem onde o componente criado pelo [styled-components](https://styled-components.com/) é melhor utilizar na propriedade referente ao estilo de `margin` o tipo verdadeiro ou falso porque o valor só tem dois valores possivel, ***exemplo***:

```js
const Input = window.styled.input`
border: 1px solid black;
width: 200px;
height: 24px;
margin-right: ${props => props.marginRight ? '100px' : '0px'};
`;

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Input marginRight/>
      <Input />
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render( <App/> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script><script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/react-is/umd/react-is.production.min.js"></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/styled-components/dist/styled-components.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">Carregando ...</div>
```